# sql view daily email

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database view that gathers about 10 member names a day, based on when they joined.

I want to setup something where these people will automatically be emailed an html page
i have made.

and repeat this daily, at first i was going to build an asp.net page

where i would pull the view and loop through the email addresses, but i wanted to see if it was possible to do this soley in sql server 2005

Could i use a trigger or a stored procedure or i havent really used sql server agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) to send email directly from SQL Server, assuming you've set up [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

sp_send_dbmail as the others said is what you use to send the E-mail

To set it up to E-mail daily you can use a SQL Server Agent Job

In SSMS, connect to your server, then open SQL Server Agen->Jobs

In here you can set up the steps for your job and the frequency with which it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an INSERT trigger and send them an email on the spot as soon as they join.

See: sp_send_dbmail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Trigger example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TriggersSqlServer.aspx